# Запятая или тире? Замена "но" на "нет" спасёт положение?

Tags: пунктуация, редактура

> **Куда ни бросишь взгляд,** или могущественная кладка тяжёлых неотесанных
>   камней, с высокими окнами, приспособленными для ведения боя, или даже
>   если дома поскромнее, моложе, но ни одной «мертвой» плоскости, той
>   самой, что так хорошо знакома жителям мегаполисов.

Может, так:

Куда ни бросишь взгляд - или могущественная кладка тяжёлых неотесанных камней, с высокими окнами, приспособленными для ведения боя, или, даже если дома поскромнее, моложе **(пропуск достоинства, примечательности младого дома. - *Ред.*)**, нет ни одной «мёртвой» плоскости, той самой, что так хорошо знакома жителям мегаполисов.

В скобках - это я резвлюсь. Но, может, я не так поняла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Куда ни бросишь взгляд — или могущественная кладка тяжёлых неотесанных камней с высокими окнами, приспособленными для ведения боя, или  дома поскромнее, помоложе, но ни одной «мертвой» плоскости, той самой, что так хорошо знакома жителям мегаполисов.

1) **Тире ставится обязательно,** оно и  без однородных отношений довольно часто ставится, например: Брынцалов ― лишь одна из наиболее заметных фигур такого типа, а вообще, **куда ни бросишь взгляд** ― тут же наткнешься на ему подобных. [Анатолий Курчаткин, 1997]

2) **Убираем одну запятую**, их должно быть минимальное количество, чтобы выразить ИЛИ...ИЛИ.

3) Всё остальное не редактируем, **потому что лучше не будет**, так что оставляем  почти авторский вариант.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вариант 2 (еще ближе к авторскому, с учетом критики товарищей)

Куда ни бросишь взгляд — или могущественная кладка тяжёлых неотесанных камней с высокими окнами, приспособленными для ведения боя, или **даже если дома поскромнее, помоложе, то и там ни одной «мертвой» плоскости**, той самой, что так хорошо знакома жителям мегаполисов.

Comment: Логично предположить,что "куда ни бросишь взгляд" относится к  отсутствию «мертвых» плоскостей, а у Вас куда ни бросишь взгляд — или кладка, или дома  поскромнее. Смысл нулевой.

Comment: Нулевой смысл? Нет проблем, сейчас исправим.

Comment: И правда, лучше стало!

Answer (score 3):

(1) Могущественная кладка камней с окнами(?!) Изменено на: мощная кладка из камней и окна.
(2) Поскромнее, моложе (?!) Изменено на: поскромнее, помоложе (или: скромнее, моложе).
(3) Смысл. Рассматриваются два варианта: старинная кладка и более современная, но ни в одном из них нет «мёртвых» плоскостей.

Мой вариант 1:

**Куда ни бросишь взгляд — или `мощная` кладка `из` тяжёлых неотесанных камней `и высокие окна`, приспособленные для ведения боя, или дома поскромнее, 
помоложе, но все равно нет ни одной «мёртвой» плоскости, той самой, что так хорошо знакома жителям мегаполисов.**

Мой вариант 2:

**Куда ни бросишь взгляд — или `мощная` кладка `из` тяжёлых неотесанных камней `и высокие окна`, приспособленные для ведения боя, или дома поскромнее, 
помоложе, — но нигде нет ни одной «мёртвой» плоскости, той самой, что так хорошо знакома жителям мегаполисов.**

В первом варианте "но все равно нет" относится к новым домам, во втором варианте "но нигде нет" выступает как обобщение.

Мой вариант 3:

**Куда ни бросишь взгляд, преобладает мощная кладка из тяжёлых неотесанных камней и высокие окна, приспособленные для ведения боя, но даже если дома поскромнее, помоложе, то все равно нет ни одной «мертвой» плоскости, той самой, что так хорошо знакома жителям мегаполисов.**

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что "бросать взгляд" - действие сравнительно направленное (если не адресованное кому-то), по сравнению с "киданием" (большое взглядом "окидывают"). "Той самой" плохо справляется со значением "такой же (подобной)".

> Куда ни кинешь взгляд, *там* или могущественная кладка из тяжёлых
>   неотесанных камней - с высокими окнами, приспособленными для ведения
>   боя, или дома поскромнее, помоложе; но нет ни одной «мертвой»
>   плоскости - из тех, что столь хорошо знакомы жителям мегаполисов.

**P.S.** Реабилитировал "*могущественную*" - "могущественное сооружение" - обычное для архитектуры сочетание.

Comment: А как же знакомое с детства: Солнцем залиты долины,//И куда ни бросишь взгляд -//Край родной, навек любимый,//Весь цветёт, как вешний сад.?

Comment: Могущественное сооружение бывает, но могущественная кладка?!

Comment: "Могущественные стены" сплошь и рядом в книжках встречаются, чем прочие элементы "сооружений" хуже?

Comment: Субъективно: с трудом принимаю даже могущественные сооружения, могущественные стены понимаю как отдельное сооружение, не стал бы распростанять это на части, тем более на кладку (какая именно часть называется кладкой?). Объективно: в Нацкорпусе нашел только могущественные сооружения.

Comment: Примеры из книг (просто статьи находятся десятками):
Спаситель с нашего двора (Олег Касимов, 2017)
_Могущественные стены Иерусалима издалека казались..._
https://books.google.ru/books?id=TrA8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=nAH4qHSnGx&sig=u00kp9XgAYFn1M-w98uMblSZ_WU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx58evm9fZAhVB1iwKHQVZBRAQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B&f=false

Comment: Вавилон. Расцвет и гибель города Чудес (Джеймс Веллард)
_А эти волнистые холмы на равнине — могущественные стены, считавшиеся некогда одним из семи чудес света?_
https://books.google.ru/books?id=SLOTWQTIWagC&pg=PT195&lpg=PT195&dq=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=lUQjNjrQhZ&sig=6kG1aC6CYXdyqIFzC5mFkqEq01g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx58evm9fZAhVB1iwKHQVZBRAQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B&f=false

Comment: В этих примерах могущественные стены - это сооружения, а не их части (стены домов).

Comment: Если проблема в соотношении части и целого, то "могущественная рука" - распространённое сочетание.

Comment: Стены "как часть" в книжке:он появлялся внутри могущественных стен https://books.google.ru/books?id=B6mQDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT313&lpg=PT313&dq=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=jaXIRlTjs1&sig=R8zpWT8M7PqKTn2R_FbmMgAQVLo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYvrOs8dfZAhVDhqQKHYbTCpIQ6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&f=false

Comment: Он появлялся внутри могущественных стен, окружавших город. Крепостные стены - отдельное сооружение, не стены дома.   Могущественная рука - вообще из другой категории. Сила и могущество людей (и рук) у меня возражений не вызывает, в отличие от  могущественности частей дома и каменных кладок.